# Partially cover UIStatusBar with View Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to have my sidebar menu view open to the full screen height so that it covers even the status bar, but leaves the right side of the status bar visible. Right now it opens under the status bar even though I have set the view frame as

```
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
sidebarContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(-barWidth - 1, screenSize.origin.y + 10, barWidth, screenHeight + statusBarHeight)
```

My view is a direct subview of the window.

Comment: You won't be able to place views over the top of the status bar, it's either shown or not. The "normal" use case would be to hide the status bar completely when the side panel appears and have it reappear when the side panel is gone. Assuming you can't do this for your own reasons and you absolutely must have this functionality, you might try taking a snapshot of that area of the screen or something for use when the side panel is showing.

Comment: @BJHStudios I guess the status bar isn't absolutely necessary, but now I'm having the problem of being unable to hide the status bar from my menu swift file.

Answer (score 0):

Views cannot be placed in front of the status bar. Any views that go beyond the bottom of the status bar will be covered by it. Plus it's downright contrary to Apple's iOS Human interface guidelines as stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/). Also, you said you want to hide the status bar. You should only do so if you are displaying media. Don't permanently hide it as that is also against the guidelines.

Comment: @A_Tyshka  I understand that it's more convenient for users to see the status bar, which is why I only want to partially cover it when the menu opens. It gives the app a cleaner look.

Comment: I understand you think it's cleaner but to my knowledge it can't be done. Even if it could it would violate Apple's guidelines, which would seriously jeopardize your chances of making it into the App Store.